# An inequality property of a Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality

Consider two sequences $\left\{ x^{n}=\left\{ x_{k}^{n}\right\}
_{k=1}^{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty },\left\{ y^{n}=\left\{ y_{k}^{n}\right\}
_{k=1}^{n}\right\} _{n=1}^{\infty }$:

Firstly, we know that for each $k$, $x_{k}^{n}, y_{k}^{n}$ are convergent sequences. (as $n\rightarrow \infty $)

And, for each $n$ and $k\leq n$, $x_{k}^{n}, y_{k}^{n}\in \left[ 0,1\right] $. Furthermore,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}y_{k}^{n}=1$$

---

As examples,

for $n=1:$ $x^{1}=y^{1}=1$,

for $n=2$, $x^{2}=\left\{ p,1-p\right\} ,y^{2}=\left\{ q,1-q\right\} $ for
some $p,q\in \left[ 0,1\right] $ and so on

---

Furthermore,

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } x_{1}^{n}
>\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } y_{1}^{n}$$

and

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } x_{k}^{n}
<\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty } y_{k}^{n}$$ for all $k>1$

and hence

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( \sum_{k=1}^{K}x_{k}^{n}\right)
>\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( \sum_{k=1}^{K}y_{k}^{n}\right)$$

for all $K\geq 1$.

---

(proof of this implication :
For $K=1,$ we have the inequality.

For $K>1:$
$$
[
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{k=1}^{K}x_{k}^{n}=\left( \lim_{n\rightarrow
\infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}x_{k}^{n}\right) -\left( \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty
}\sum_{k=K+1}^{n}x_{k}^{n}\right) =1-\left( \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty
}\sum_{k=K+1}^{n}x_{k}^{n}\right)]
%
$$

Similarly for y sequence. Since $K>1$ and for all $k>1$ we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty
}x_{k}^{n}<\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }y_{k}^{n}$ which implies the result.)

---

Finally, $x_{k}^{n}$ and $y_{k}^{n}$ are (weakly) decreasing in $k$ for each $n$.

Is it true that for sufficiently large $n$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{k^{\ast }}x_{k}^{n}\geq \sum_{k=1}^{k^{\ast }}y_{k}^{n}
$$
for all $k^{\ast }\leq n?$

---

At first, I thought that the answer to the question below is immediately "Yes" but I am now a little bit worried whether it is the case. I am worried since for each $n$ the size of the sequence changes and still all sum up to 1.

Comment: I don't believe that the inequality following "and hence" actually follows from the previous two inequalities; I think it needs to be another hypothesis.

Comment: I believe it is true since x_{k}^{n} and y_{k}^{n} sum to 1 (over k) See the proof added.

Comment: The example $x^n = (\frac23,\frac13,0,\dots)$, $y^n = (\frac12,\frac12,0,\dots)$ shows that you need nonstrict inequality at the very least. You're implicitly switching two limits - the limit as $n\to\infty$, and the limit implicit in the eventual infinite sum over $k$. This requires justification, such as uniform convergence. It might be true, but I'm not yet convinced....

Comment: If I understood the example correctly, it does not satisfy the requirement: $x_{k}^{n}=y_{k}^{n}$ for all n when k>2. So, strict inequality should be okay if otherwise correct. For the implicit limits: I will need to think over.

Answer (score 2):

It's not true. Let the sequences $x^n$ look like (starting with $n=3$):
$$
(\tfrac12,0,\tfrac12), \, (\tfrac12,0,0,\tfrac12), \, (\tfrac12,0,0,0,\tfrac12), \,\dots
$$
while the sequences $y^n$ look like
$$
(\tfrac13,\tfrac23,0), \, (\tfrac13,0,\tfrac23,0), \, (\tfrac13,0,0,\tfrac23,0), \,\dots.
$$
These satisfy all of your conditions; in particular,
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( \sum_{k=1}^{K}x_{k}^{n}\right) = \frac12 > \frac13 = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\left( \sum_{k=1}^{K}y_{k}^{n}\right)
$$
for every $K\ge1$. However, when $k^*=n-1$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{k^{\ast }}x_{k}^{n} = \frac12 < 1 = \sum_{k=1}^{k^{\ast }}y_{k}^{n}.
$$

Similar examples can be made that are weakly decreasing (and satisfy the other new hypotheses): for example, set
$$
x^n = \bigg( \frac34, \frac18, \frac1{16}, \dots, \frac1{2^{n-1}}, \frac1{2^n}, \frac1{2^n} \bigg)
$$
and
$$
y^n = \bigg( \frac12, \frac14, \frac18, \dots, \frac1{2^{n-2}}, \frac1{2^{n-2}}, 0 \bigg).
$$

Comment: Thanks. That is absolutely a valid example for the assumptions given. I actually noticed that I have a stronger assumption (which I edited for). Do you think this fixes the problem so that the claim is true? Thank you again for your nice example and sorry to everyone for missing assumptions.

Comment: @Ava: I've edited the answer to include what I think is still a counterxample.